# looping through gridview using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

i am trying to loop through a gridview using jquery,
the code i am using is

```
$('#<%=gridview1.clientid%> tbody tr').not(':first,:last')
  .each(function(){
    gridrows ++;
  });
```

i would like to eliminate the first and last rows which are obviously the header and footer , i tried this code but seems that it is not working, it is returning the count of gridview rows. any ideas.

Comment: Are you using some kind of plugin for *gridrows++* or its just a pseudo-code for some underlying logic......

Comment: wow a comment after almost 1 year and 10 months, any way it was pseudocode and i was able to solve it using the link in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible things to consider:

(1) Try to avoid mixing your server code in your jquery. 
Just use the gridview's ID property $('#myGridView') 
instead of getting it through the brackets. (Maybe 
you weren't trying to do that, though.)

(2) Have a read of Rick Strahl's post on this topic. 
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/822827.aspx

I believe you'll find it covers the problem you're encountering now.

Comment: that article is a very useful one. thanks for the pointer,@adam kiss sorry i missed the link in mg's answer so now i can add thead to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `<tbody>`, why not use `<thead>`for header and `<tfoot>` for footer?

```
<table>
  <thead><tr>..</tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr>..</tr></tbody>
  <tfoot><tr>..</tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

?

Then you can lose the `.not()` part. Also, are you *sure* that that ASP.net code returns existing id? :)

Comment: i belive gridview will not generate thead so i have to live with tbody,